# при добавлении новой записи через vue.js вызывать axios непосредственно в методе определенного компонента или через vuex?

Tags: vue.js

```
в vuex вызываю для получения всех записей из БД и сохранение в vuex для дальнейшего использования, а как насчет добавлении одной записи в БД

как правильней это вызывать прямо в компоненте или реализовать это в vuex и импортировать в компонент mapActions и вызывать этот Actions?
        methods:{
          addProduct()
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: window.location.origin + '/api/v1/products/products',
            })
                .then(response => {
                  
                    console.log(response)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error)
                })
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы уже используете Vuex - то все асинхронные действия (они же `actions`) лучше объявлять в сторе и переиспользовать их. В вашем случае нужно создать экшн в сторе, обратиться к нему в компоненте и передавать нужный вам payload.

Comment: переиспользовать имеете ввиду этого же типа? к примеру если это сохранение post то action делать же не универсальный типа и для post сохранения и для product   и т.д.

Comment: @user484713 я имею ввиду ситуацию когда вы будете иметь возможность сохранить условный "список покупок" из нескольких компонентов, обращаясь всего лишь к одному и тому же экшну.